# how to give space btw array elements or break, to display two different types of arrays

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$var=10;
$var2= "hello";
echo "hello  ".$var."test<br>".$var2;
$cars = array("volvo","BMW","Toyata");
echo $cars[0].$cars[1].$cars[2];
$age = array("Simran"=>"20","Kamo"=>"30","Indu"=>"40");
$arrlength = count($age);
echo $arrlength;
echo $age['Simran'];
$mul = array(array("Sunny","Day"),array("Simran"=>"30","jan"=>"jatin"));
echo $mul[1]['jan'].$mul[0][1];
?>
```

I want output be like :

Hello Test

Volvo BMW Toyta

30  20

jatin day

Comment: It is exactly the same as you did on line -> echo "hello  " ....

Comment: Concatenate spaces, or include them in the array assignment... or use HTML elements and CSS styling.

Comment: echo " "; will print space and echo "<br>"; will print line break

Comment: @lurii Drozdov 
 ty sir but I know this thing. but how echo " " will work btw array elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare your code with below code to get an idea to print string to new line.

```
<?php
$var=10;
$var2= "hello";
echo "hello"." "."test"."<br>";
$cars = array("volvo","BMW","Toyata");
echo implode(" ", $cars)."<br>";
$age = array("Simran"=>"20","Kamo"=>"30","Indu"=>"40");
$arrlength = count($age);
echo $age['Kamo']." ".$age['Simran']."<br>";
$mul = array(array("Sunny","Day"),array("Simran"=>"30","jan"=>"jatin"));
echo $mul[1]['jan']." ".$mul[0][1];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it work for me .. :)

I got new element "implode", I will study it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "hello Test <br>";
$cars = array("volvo","BMW","Toyata");
echo $cars[0].' '.$cars[1].' '.$cars[2].'<br>';
$age = array("Simran"=>"20","Kamo"=>"30","Indu"=>"40");
$arrlength = count($age);
//echo $arrlength;
echo $age['Kamo'].' '.$age['Simran'].'<br>';
$mul = array(array("Sunny","Day"),array("Simran"=>"30","jan"=>"jatin"));
echo $mul[1]['jan'].' '.$mul[0][1];
?>
```

This will return as you want, Hope this will help you.